# How can I wrap text within a merged cell with tabulararray

Tags: tabularray

I am working to create a table with alternating rows—the first has 5 columns and the second is a merged column that just consists of text.

However, I can't for the life of me, get it to wrap the text. I have tried `hspan=minimal`, Q columns, and X columns (albeit perhaps incorrectly?)

Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={@{}c|Q[l]|c|c|c|@{}},
    width=\linewidth
}
Thing 1 & Thing 2 & Thing 3 & Thing 4  & Thing 5\\
\SetCell[c=5]{c} I am a dummy string tall and skinny! Here is where I start start start! This is where I sing! There is my middle! And last we have my end end end!& & & & \\
\end{tblr}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the total width of the merged cell:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={@{}X[c]|X[l]|X[c]|X[c]|X[c]|@{}},
    width=\linewidth
}
Thing 1 & Thing 2 & Thing 3 & Thing 4  & Thing 5\\
\SetCell[c=5]{\linewidth,halign=l} I am a dummy string tall and skinny! Here is where I start start start! This is where I sing! There is my middle! And last we have my end end end!& & & & \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(I replaced your `c` columns with `X[c]` so the table has a change to fill the width you specified equally and not enlarging just the last column.)

Comment: I am going to name my first child samcarter!

For bonus points, can you tell me if there is a way to have it right-align with the text on the right using this colspec instead (I had made a mistake)—it's quite similar.

`colspec={@{}Q[l]|Q[l]|Q[c]|Q[c]|Q[r]|@{}},`

Comment: @Jesse Are you maybe looking for `halign=r` or `halign=j`? If not, can you please make a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was ignorant of `halign=j`—thank you so much!

Hey, where is the best/most complete documentation on this?

Comment: @Jesse You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the selector `cell{row(s)}{column(s)}` to define a multispan cell. Then you should use `hspan = minimal`

As described on [tabularray docs](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) in 3.1.4 **Hspan and Vspan Algorithms**:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

% Random text
% Don't use this on your document
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {*{5}X},
        hlines,
        vlines,
        % minimal span
        hspan=minimal,
        width = 1\columnwidth,
        rows = {
            valign = m,
            halign = c
        },
        % cell in row 5 column 1 will have a
        % colspan of 5 (c=5), for rowspan use r=#
        cell{5}{1} = {c=5}{},
        % alignment for row 5
        row{5} = {
            halign = j
        },
    }
        1 & {835\\ 586} & 158 & 878 & 274 \\
        2 & 285 & 608 & 904 & 285 \\
        3 & 107 & 230 & 358 & 368 \\
        4 & 415 & 301 & 182 & 147 \\
        \lipsum[1] &&&&
    \end{tblr}
% Termina nuestro documento
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this answer, but how can I make it fit the entire `\linewidth` (this just sizes it to the headers, right)?

Comment: @Jesse As you see, when specifying X columns you must define the key `width`, on this key you must specify what you want. I used in this example `\columnwidth`, you can use `\textwidth` or something similar

Comment: If that's not what you asked for, could you explain it in more detail please? I'm not a native speaker so maybe I'm missing something XD

Comment: In your case you  need to define table width only when you like that table width is narrower (or wider, but this is not recommended) than width of environment (in your case the width of text area, i. e. `\textwidth`}. Of course,  complete table has  the same width, but when you use `talltblr`, the caption width can not be wider than table. +1 for nice answer!